# Naming folder "Framework.Service" appends ".app" extension which can't be removed

Tags: finder, filesystem, folders

I'm currently having a really weird problem. I've checked out a git repo which has a folder named `Framework.Service`. When I run `ls` in the terminal it shows the folder name as is. But when I look at it in Finder it's actually called `Framework.Service.app`.

You can simply recreate this yourself by creating a folder with that name anywhere in Finder.

Why is this happening and how do I prevent it? If it would only affect Finder I wouldn't mind too much, but even my IDE (Rider) can't correctly resolve the file path because it expects it without the `.app` extension.